# How do I search for a specific String of a place using Google Maps

Tags: android, string, google-maps

Good day all. 
I am working on an Android Application and could use a little help.

I am trying to figure out the proper syntax for searching within Google maps for a specific location. 
IE, I am located at (lat, lng) and would like to find all stores/ shops that are named "Walmart" near those coordinates.

I have done some research and it seems like multiple people recommend using "Google Places", but as Google maps has changed dramatically lately, I was unsure if it had been deprecated.

Updated the code as per the recommendations:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public double[] searchForStuff(){
    final String searchString = "Starbucks";

    final double[] placeLocations = new double[2];



    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread (new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{

                final URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(searchString) + "&sensor=true");

                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                br.close();

                JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                JSONObject result = mainObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0); // Array of location objects
                JSONObject geometry = result.getJSONObject("geometry");
                JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

                double latitude = location.getDouble("lat");
                double longitude = location.getDouble("lng");

                placeLocations[0] = latitude;
                placeLocations[1] = longitude;


            } catch (IOException e) {
                String error = e.toString();
            } catch (Exception e){
                String error = e.toString();
            }

        }   
    });// 


    backgroundThread.start();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Is this working? " + placeLocations[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG); //Nope :(
    return placeLocations;



}
```

Still having errors though

-Sil

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                + URLEncoder.encode(address) + "&sensor=true");
        // address is a string variable, "Walmart" for example

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        br.close();

        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        JSONObject result = mainObject.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0); // Array of location objects
        JSONObject geometry = result.getJSONObject("geometry");
        JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

        double latitude = location.getDouble("lat");
        double longitude = location.getDouble("lng");
```

Array of objects named "results" is list of locations.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working :(. Just keeps returning 0, 0

Comment: Look at result JSON in browser http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Walmart&sensor=true. It returns correct locations.

Comment: Updated the code, but still not able to return anything. Not sure what the issue is, but I will continue with it tomorrow. Thank you for the help Roman

Comment: Try to debug Yoyr code and look what StringBuilder contains after download.